# Parameters in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

hello everyone I just want to know that what the code inside *** is doing here cz even if i dont write that still I m getting my output?

For example, imagine that we need user information on a user profile page
    (/v1/users/azat defined as /v1/users/:username) and on an admin page
    (/v1/admin/azat defined as /v1/admin/:username). One way to do this is to define a
    function that looks up the user information (findUserByUsername) and call this function
    twice inside of each of the routes. This is how we can implement it (example ch4/app.js):

```
    var users = {
    'azat': {
    email: 'hi@azat.co',
    website: 'http://azat.co',
    blog: 'http://webapplog.com'
    }
    };

    ***var findUserByUsername = function (username, callback) {
    // Perform database query that calls callback when it's done
    // This is our fake database
    if (!users[username])
    return callback(new Error(
    'No user matching '
    + username
    )
    );
    return callback(null, users[username]);
    };***

    app.get('/v1/users/:username', function(request, response, next) {
    var username = request.params.username;
    findUserByUsername(username, function(error, user) {
    if (error) return next(error);
    return response.render('user', user);
    });
    });

    app.get('/v1/admin/:username', function(request, response, next) {
    var username = request.params.username;
    findUserByUsername(username, function(error, user) {
    if (error) return next(error);
    return response.render('admin', user);
    });
 });
```

Comment: what do you mean by don't write the function findUserByUsername?

Comment: @R.Sarkar i meant even If I am removing the function I am still getting the expected output ..and what i wanna know is what this function is doing?

Comment: findUserByName function takes two parameter, second one is the callBack function. Based upon the value of users callback function is getting called either with error or result. return is not required in anywhere of your code. If you remove the function definition you should get an error.Hope this will help you.